# Nested loop in iMacros (2nd loop)

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, macros, imacros

Hoping you could help me make a nested loop work with iMacros.

1. First loop: Loops all rows of source.csv (col A, multiple rows)
2. Second loop (**X**): Grab all the List elements found on hxxp://site.com/?what={{!COL1}}

*After a lot of work I feel I am finally getting somewhere:*

The problem in the script is that I cannot get Loop `{{n}}` to grab all the positions of the page (list items).
Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
var macro;
macro =  "CODE:";
macro +=  "VERSION BUILD=000000" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAB T=1" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE source.csv" + "\n";
macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1 " + "\n";
macro +=  "SET !LOOP 1" + "\n"; 
//macro +=  "SET !TIMEOUT 3" + "\n";
macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}}" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "URL GOTO=http://site.com/?what={{!COL1}} " + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS={{n}} TYPE=LI ATTR=CLASS:classofdiv" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS={{n}} TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=All_list_items.txt" + "\n"; 

for (var i=1;i<20;i++)
{
iimSet("i",i)
iimPlay(macro)
iimSet("n",i)//<-- How to grab all the TAG POS of the website?
}
```

**Edit 1.1** - I should point out that I use the term `{{n}}` as example to loop list items (div-ul-li-span). If replaced with 'POS=1' the script works, but ofcourse only saves the first list item instead of all the list items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to grab all the positions of POS=x ?

Try this out:

```
var macro;
macro =  "CODE:";
macro +=  "VERSION BUILD=000000" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAB T=1" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE source.csv" + "\n";
macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1 " + "\n";
macro +=  "SET !LOOP 1" + "\n"; 
//macro +=  "SET !TIMEOUT 3" + "\n";
macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}}" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "URL GOTO=http://site.com/?what={{!COL1}} " + "\n"; 

var macro1;
macro1 =  "CODE:";
macro1 +=  "TAG POS={{n}} TYPE=LI ATTR=CLASS:classofdiv" + "\n"; 
macro1 +=  "TAG POS={{n}} TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n"; 
macro1 +=  "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=All_list_items.txt" + "\n"; 

for (var i=1;i<20;i++)
{
iimSet("i",i)
iimPlay(macro)


//set counter
var n=1;
//this is infinite loop
while(true)
{
iimSet("n",n)//<-- How to grab all the TAG POS of the website?

var ret=iimPlay(macro1);

//if macro didn't find any more positions it breaks from this loop
//and reads new link from the csv file
if(ret<0)
{
break;
}

//increase counter
n++;
}//end of while loop

}//end of for loop
```

This will enable macro1 to loop inside while loop as long as there is new position each time. This might not work so give us feedback.

Comment: Changed macro2 to macro1. Thank you, the second loop works! So there is my solution.

Comment: Great. How do I get that +50 bounty? In future ask any question related to iMacros and I will try to respond.