# iMacros .if .else captcha

Tags: imacros

Good afternoon! I've a code with bypass captcha service written in iMacros.My problem is..
I need to do that if my captcha is incorrect then to do it again like a loop or if captcha is good then go next part of code.
How can i do that in iMacros.I heard about javascript there but can't make up code.
Please, look at my code.

```
URL GOTO="my site"

TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:"my options"

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO ATTR=ID:"my options"
wait seconds=2

SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO

ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=C:\Captcha\ FILE=image.jpg WAIT=YES

TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:"image captcha" CONTENT=EVENT:SAVEPICTUREAS

tab open

tab t=2

URL GOTO="service captcha"

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:pict CONTENT=C:\Captcha\image.jpg

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:"submit send captcha"
ATTR=VALUE:Send

TAG POS=6 TYPE=TD ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT

wait seconds=3

SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=NAME:account ATTR=ID:Passwd CONTENT="my password"

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=NAME:account ATTR=ID:PasswdAgain CONTENT="my 
password"

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:account ATTR=ID:Email CONTENT="email"

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:account ATTR=ID:newaccountcaptcha CONTENT={{!var1}}

wait seconds=2

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:account ATTR=ID:submitbutton
```

Ok.Some times captcha is incorrect in form and it gives me one message like that
" The characters you entered are wrong " .How can i repeat these steps again with javascript?
I'm only interested in the preventive methods cauze iMacros is interesting analog then other programs.
Thanks you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You have an example here how you can use JavaScript Scripting and make nested loops.

[Nested loop in iMacros (2nd loop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402012/nested-loop-in-imacros-2nd-loop)