# How to run two loops by iMacros?

Tags: javascript, loops, imacros

I'm on Firefox 55.0.2 (64-bit), iMacros 9.0.3, Windows10 x64.

I'm trying to get all HREFs from all website pages and fail on two loops.

However, the looping works, but after every founded link, the URL is reloaded. This is my iMacro code:

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAB T=1

SET !DATASOURCE links.csv 
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
WAIT SECONDS=15

TAG XPATH="(//body//a)[{{!LOOP}}]" EXTRACT=HREF

ADD !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}

SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=links.csv
```

Then I tried it another way, with this code related to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18435002/1992004.

```
var macro;
macro =  "CODE:";
macro +=  "VERSION BUILD=9030808" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAB T=1" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE links.csv" + "\n";
macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1 " + "\n";
macro +=  "SET !LOOP 1" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}}" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "URL GOTO={{!COL1}} " + "\n"; 
macro +=  "WAIT SECONDS=15" + "\n"; 

var macro1;
macro1 =  "CODE:";
macro1 +=  "TAG POS={{n}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:* EXTRACT=HREF" + "\n"; 
macro1 +=  "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=links.csv" + "\n"; 

for (var i=1;i<20;i++)
{
iimSet("i",i)
iimPlay(macro)

var n=1;

while(true)
{
iimSet("n",n)

var ret=iimPlay(macro1);

if(ret<0)
{
break;
}

n++;
}

}
```

I saved the last code as `.iim` and `.js`:

- In the case of `.iim` I get an error `MacroSyntaxError: unknown command: VAR, line 1 (Error code: -910)`.
- In the case of `.js`, I get the error `The LOOP button can only be used with macro (".iim") files. In a Javascript (".js") file, you can use Javascript itself for loops.`.

What would be the correct code to get both loops to work?

[@Shugar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4270557/shugar) [@macroscripts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1452141/macroscripts) [@chivracq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3799241/chivracq) do you probably have a hint for me?

Comment: Hum..., tagging a User in the Qt-Body doesn't seem to work, I didn't get any Notif... (but I had seen your Qt yesterday already). / Well, simply read the Error Msg's, they are perfectly "explanatory", => yep, the 2nd Script is a '.js' Script, and needs to be played with the `Play` Button (and not the `Play (Loop)` one), ... and would be "the" Script to use (... to extract ALL Links for the first 20 URLs/Sites in your DataSource), your 1st Script (in '.iim') only tries to extract "diagonally" 1st Link on URL_1, then 2nd Link on URL_2 etc while you want to extract all Links per Site...

Comment: @chivracq as always, very helpful. Thank you, immediately got it to work. One question remains: how is it possible to use the same file as datasource and as export file? I want to write exports into a file and to to loop through its first column for taking next url to visit. I tried both set datasource and download directory setting to the same directory, and to explicitely write the file path into imacros code - nothing helped.

Comment: Hum, Okay..., should rather use v8.9.7 for FF, works also on FF v55.0.2 (I use it myself on FF v55.0.3), v9.0.3 for FF is/was completely Buggy and started messing up with "Things" that were working before... // Yep, => use the `FOLDER` Param either for `SAVEAS` and/or for `!DATASOURCE` to specify the same Folder where you want to save/keep/maintain your "Links.csv" File... (But from v9.0.3 for FF I think, `FILEDELETE` if you need it didn't work anymore (by Design) in `\DataSources\\`, only in `\Downloads\\`...)

Comment: Site is Buggy like usual, last part is meant as: "... `FILEDELETE` doesn't work anymore in '\DataSources\', only in '\Downloads\'..." // Can't combine a 2nd `\\` for a Path in Backtiks apparently, oh well...! I don't complain anymore, ah-ah...!